# Why doesn't pointers change the value until function stops working?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

So i'm writing a snake game using arrays, and i have to change the values of the row and column, not create copies, therefore i'm using pointers.

```
void pointerset(int *rowPtr,int *colPtr){
*rowPtr=rand()%25;
*colPtr=rand()%64;
}
void create_snake(int *rowPtr,int *colPtr,int row,int column,int x){

pointerset(rowPtr,colPtr);

printf("%d %d",row,column);

if(board[row][column]==1){
  create_snake(rowPtr,colPtr,row,column,x);

}else if(board[row][column]==0){
    board[row][column]=x;

}else{
    create_snake(rowPtr,colPtr,row,column,x);
}

}
int main(){

int row=0,column=0;

int *rowPtr;
   rowPtr=&row;
int *colPtr;
   colPtr=&column;
create_snake(rowPtr,colPtr,row,column,x);
}
```

I need to change these variables' values, and also check if they're at the place i want. I have a function to create my snake on the gameboard.

the creating snake function is here, there are parameters for row and column also, so that i can use them on the array and do a checkup, but i also used pointers, so that i'll change row's and column's values before using the actual row and column

To give random numbers for row and column, there was another function.

I've tried to see where the variable's value's change, therefore i used a

```
printf("%d %d",row,column);
```

When i use it in the function `create_snake()` it gives me 0 0 for row and column, when i use this printf under the function `create_snake()` in main, after function works and stops, it gives me random numbers i've created, rather than 0 0 but i need them to change when the function works. I simply couldn't solve where i failed using pointers.

I've created the function `pointerset()` because if i was simply writing

```
*rowPtr=rand()%25;
*colPtr=rand()%64;
```

to the function `create_snake()` it wasn't working.

Comment: The `row` and `col` argument for the function are *copies* of the original values, but accessing them through the pointers gets or sets the *original* values. So in the function, `board[row][column]` remains `board[0][0]`.

Comment: how can i change this situation then? @WeatherVane

Comment: you need to change your algorithm

Comment: I don't understand why you passed `row` and `column` to the function as well as pointers to them. You could remove the `row` and `column` arguments from the function, and work with `*rowPtr` and `*colPtr`.

Comment: because im doing a check on the board, so i need the variables themselves, as the array doesnt accept pointers for index numbers. @WeatherVane

Comment: You mean you can't index the array with `board[*rowPtr][*colPtr]`? On algorithm, I think you should establish the board size as the first thing before doing anything else. It's a tangle.

Comment: ok nvm, it worked, thanks :D i've done the changes in argument and i just found about something about pointer i didn't know

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So here is the thing,
*rowPtr gets the integer value of the pointer, while rowPTr doesnt( i guess gives memory adress? im not sure)

i removed the arguments in the function called `row` and `column` but instead used pointer for everything.

I thought i couldn't use pointers to check my board which is an array for their index, but i can simply type `board[*rowPtr][*colPtr]`  and it works, i was writing without asteriks.